# Why was this question about downloading / uploading put on hold as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1360889/why-cant-we-just-upload-a-file-and-it-reaches-its-destination-without-the-other), the asker seems to be asking about how bandwidth usage is counted. A possible misunderstanding of its accounting may have led the asker to believe that if bandwidth is "used" by the uploader, then the downloader shouldn't also have it counted against them. The question, "Isn't this double-counting?" may arise and lead directly to the titular question (paraphrased), "Why can't we upload directly without it counting as a download?".

Regardless of what exactly this person is asking, the fundamentals of downloading, uploading, and bandwidth seems very relevant to home networking, and thus, SU. Why is this question considered off-topic? Could someone clarify?

Comment: "Why can't we upload directly without it counting as a download?" That's not what he is asking as far as can understand what is a poor question.

Comment: It's a very fundamental question, but it's clear.  Beginner questions are on-topic.  grawity wrote a good answer and deleted it.  I agree with you, and voted to reopen.

Comment: What I worry is the author wants to know, "Can someone please explain how the data is transmitted over the Internet", which is way to broad.  As you know, the answer to that question, is complicated since not every method is created equal.